# Big list of journals with free access to back issues.

Tags: big-list

Now, I love it when I find a journal which allows free access to its back issues ! I propose to build a big list of such journals and I will start by putting down my own contributions.

Comment: I think this question would serve better as a community wiki, and at least one flagger agrees. If you disagree, the action can be undone, but I would like to see the matter discussed in meta first.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Community wiki is fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Recreational Mathematics**

- **Ludus Opuscula RMM**

This journal is very new. They allow access to all their articles on their websites.

Answer (score 1):

**Canadian Mathematical Society**

I absolutely adore the CMS because of the amount of material they give out for free !

- **Crux Mathematicorum**

This journal is dedicated solely to problem solving. It includes problems from Olympiads from around the world, a problem section where readers can propose problems and where solutions are published. It also has an excellent book-review section which never fails to inform me about excellent books I didn't know about before !

- **Canadian Mathematical Bulletin**

This journal is dedicated to publishing short results and proofs.

- **Canadian Journal of Mathematics**

This is their flagship journal.

- **Fibonacci Quarterly**

This is not exactly produced by CMS, but they acknowledge CMS' help in their homepage. I have included it here for brevity' sake instead of making another answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Nieuw Archief Voor Wiskunde** from The Netherlands has been around for at least two decades, and I am sure it is still going strong. You can access the journal almost free of charge.

**Asia Pacific Mathematical Newsletter** is as good as the American Mathematical Monthly which has a problem section with very interesting and challenging problems that is also free to access.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but is the first journal written in English ?

Comment: Yes, it is. The problems in this journal are hard. I recall most successful solvers do hold a PhD in math for this particular journal.

Comment: Do you know how I can embed links in my answers ?

Comment: You can look up mathjack for this/

Comment: Please post a link where I can read it in English. Google search gave me a non-English website.